# Python kivy - меняется размер кнопок при изменении их количества. Как это убрать?

Tags: python, kivy

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую под ней добавляется другие кнопки. Проблема в том, что я задал размер BoxLayout, чтобы он не занимал весь экран, и теперь при добавлении новых кнопок у них меняется размер, они уменьшаются, так как их суммарный размер постоянный. Как сделать так, чтобы новые кнопки просто добавлялись под старыми, не меняя размер старых?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class MyApp(App):   
    
    button_amount = 2

    def build(self):

        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical',
            size_hint = [None, None],
            size = [300,100 * MyApp.button_amount])
        btn1 = Button(text="Создать группу",
            size = [300,200])

        bl.add_widget(btn1)
        al.add_widget(bl)

        def new_group(self):
            btn2 = Button(text = "Новая группа")
            bl.add_widget(btn2)
            MyApp.button_amount += 1

        btn1.bind(on_release=new_group)

        return al

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        scroll = ScrollView(
            size_hint=(0.5, 0.7), pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        )
        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid.bind(minimum_height=self.grid.setter("height"))
        button = Button(
            text="Создать группу",
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=dp(200),
            on_release=self.new_group,
        )

        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        self.grid.add_widget(button)
        scroll.add_widget(self.grid)
        return screen

    def new_group(self, *args):
        self.grid.add_widget(
            Button(text="Новая группа", size_hint_y=None, height=dp(100))
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```